# boto3 describe VPC connections - where is the region?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am looking to create a 'topology' of all my VPC's which are peered. In essence, I have an 'origin' vpc, and from their, I am querying all the peers to see their zones, subnets, peer ids, etc... However, when I query the peered connections, I cannot for the life of me get the region of each 'accepter'! My current method:

```
connections = (self.client.describe_vpc_peering_connections())["VpcPeeringConnections"]
```

How do I get the region for these connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`connections['VpcPeeringConnections']['RequesterVpcInfo']['Region']`

Refernce: [EC2 Client documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_vpc_peering_connections)

Comment: I read that in the documentation too and was confused why I wasn't seeing it. Upon upgrading boto3, it appeared. Thank you!